# Measuring color difference from an ROI within the image using DeltaE color difference?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, euclidean-distance

1. I have to read one RGB image
2. then I need to select an ROI
3. After that, I need to measure the colour difference of the ROI from the entire image using simple 
   colour segmentation ( not using HSV image, I am asked to convert RGB to Lab image)
4. the output will be, the ROI highlighted and the background will be grey.
5. simple colour segmentation with deltaE colour difference is needed using python.
6. there can be more than one objects present in the mask after colour segmentation.
7. then I am instructed to analyse the depth of the ROI and segment the ROI according to the depth 
   value of the ROI.
       But here it is not being possible to get the deltaE over the whole image as well.
    please help, I need it badly.

   I have this image to work on, from here I need to segment the hand gesture part:
   [enter image description here][1]

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGA42.jpg

   I have coded this far :
       ''''

   ```
   # Open image and make Numpy arrays 'rgb' and 'lab'
   pic = imageio.imread('E:\JU_V2_DIGIT\RGB_Crop\RGB_P7_G0_8.png')
   pic2 = pic.copy()
   # Determine the shape of the image
   total_row, total_col, layers = pic2.shape
   mask= np.zeros_like(pic2)
   x,y = np.ogrid[:total_row, :total_col]
   # Transform in lab picture
   Lab_pic = color.rgb2lab(pic)
   L_pic, A_pic, B_pic = cv2.split(Lab_pic)


   cv2.imshow("L_Channel", L_pic)  # For L Channel
   cv2.imshow("A_Channel", A_pic)  # For A Channel
   cv2.imshow("B_Channel", B_pic)  # For B Channel

   cen_x, cen_y = total_row/2, total_col/2
   distance_from_center = np.sqrt((x-cen_x+10)**2+(y-cen_y-15)**2)
   radius = (total_row/3)
   circular_pic = distance_from_center>radius
   pic2[circular_pic] = 0
   pic2[mask] = 0
   #cv2.imwrite('D:\SHROUTI\Testpictures\opencvmasking_human.jpg',dst)
   cv2.imshow("cir_mask",pic2)
   Lab = color.rgb2lab(pic2)

   #getting mean value for the mask region
   L_mask,A_mask,B_mask = cv2.split(Lab)

   cv2.imshow("L_Channel_mask", L_mask)  # For L Channel
   cv2.imshow("A_Channel_mask", A_mask)  # For A Channel
   cv2.imshow("B_Channel_mask", B_mask)  # For B Channel

   LMean = L_mask.mean()
   AMean = A_mask.mean()
   BMean = B_mask.mean()


   # getting delta values
   DeltaL = L_pic-LMean
   DeltaA = A_pic- AMean
   DeltaB = B_pic - BMean

   DeltaE = np.sqrt(pow(DeltaA,2)+pow(DeltaB,2)+pow(DeltaL,2))
   print(DeltaE)
   cv2.imshow("deltaE",DeltaE)
   cv2.waitKey()
   ```

   ''' 
   It shows a complete white output image. I am not getting what to do. Please help

Comment: why are you using multiple image processing libraries? why not open and convert the images in opencv also?

Comment: beside the display problem consider re-reading the problem description. your implementation suggests that you might not really understand what it asked. for example, why do you calculate the mean for the entire image? you need the mean for the ROI only

Answer (score 0):

Your DeltaE is displayed white because you put a float64 array with values below 230 into cv2.imshow()

It expects all values to be within [0,1]. In your case every value >= 1 becomes 255 and therefor your output image is all white.

```
normalized = cv2.normalize(DeltaE, None, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

or

```
normalized = cv2.normalize(DeltaE, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype = cv2.CV_8U)
```

to get a normalized version of `DeltaE` that you may display without issues.

A solution to this is found by clicking google's first hit for "imshow white" btw.

I don't understand why you use three different image processing libraries for this.

OpenCV covers all your needs.

replace `pic = imageio.imread('E:\JU_V2_DIGIT\RGB_Crop\RGB_P7_G0_8.png')`
with

`pic = cv2.imread('E:\JU_V2_DIGIT\RGB_Crop\RGB_P7_G0_8.png')`

```
Lab_pic = color.rgb2lab(pic)
```

with

```
Lab = cv2.cvtColor(pic2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
```

and so forth...

No need to risk weird things because one library works in BRG while another in RGB or whatever. Just in case you wondered why your rgb image looks so weird.